# Android Internet Connection Check Failure

Tags: android, android-networking

I am using following code to identify whether the phone is connected to internet or not.

```
public static boolean isOnline(Context context) {  
    try {
        ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) 
        context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);  
        return cm.getActiveNetworkInfo().isConnectedOrConnecting();
    } catch(Exception e) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

with this check, when phone is connected home wifi but note that there is no internet connection, still this method is returning me true. which is causing my application to crash as when it tries the code assuming internet is there, I can put further exception handling to prevent the crashes, but I need a better way to check internet connectivity which can return actual internet connection status...

Answer (score 0):

Use this :

```
public  boolean isConnected() {
        boolean conectado;
        if (conectivtyManager.getActiveNetworkInfo() != null
                && conectivtyManager.getActiveNetworkInfo().isAvailable()
                && conectivtyManager.getActiveNetworkInfo().isConnected()) {
            conectado = true;
        } else {
            conectado = false;
        }
        return conectado;
    }
```

Place this permission:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
```

Comment: Don't forget the permissions, also checking for roaming might be a good idea. See my answer.

Comment: I've added permissions... when I switch of the wi-fi on phone then it tells me that there is no internet but when I connect it back though there is no internet it says there is

Comment: @AmolKamble use this method and don't forget to place the permission,it shall works

Comment: Would this method be affected if I'm connected to wi-fi and thats forming an intranet?

Comment: I'm not sure but , I think it wouldn't be a problem

Answer (score 0):

I always use:

```
public static boolean isOnline(Context ctx) {

    NetworkInfo info = (NetworkInfo) ((ConnectivityManager) ctx.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE)).getActiveNetworkInfo();
    if (info == null || !info.isConnected()) {
        return false;
    }
    if (info.isRoaming()) {
        // here is the roaming option you can change it if you want to
        // disable internet while roaming, just return false
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

There's an extra check if the device is roaming, when `true`, it suggests that use of data on this network may incur extra costs.

Don't forget to add the right permission to your manifest outside the `<application>` tag:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```

Comment: I don't think roaming is an issue. Anyway I tried your way but no luck.

Comment: You might wanna post your DDMS log. This should work. Have you add permissions?

Comment: have added <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission>
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />

Comment: again, we can't help you without logs, because it should work. There's nothing wrong with the code.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
public boolean networkCheckIn(){
try{

ConnectivityManager networkInfo = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(MapViewActivity.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE) ;
networkInfo.getActiveNetworkInfo().isConnectedOrConnecting() ;

Log.d("1", "Net avail:"
                + networkInfo.getActiveNetworkInfo().isConnectedOrConnecting());

ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(MapViewActivity.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
 NetworkInfo netInfo = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
 if (netInfo != null && netInfo.isConnectedOrConnecting()) {
    //Log.d("2", "Network available:true");
     return true;

  } else {
            //Log.d("3", "Network available:false");
            return false;
   }

}catch(Exception e){
        return false ;
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is the method [`getActiveNetworkInfo()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/ConnectivityManager.html#getActiveNetworkInfo%28%29).

An example, to get network state of Wi-Fi:

```
public static boolean isWifiAvailable(Context context) {
    ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    if (cm == null)
        return false;

    NetworkInfo[] networkInfos = cm.getAllNetworkInfo();
    for (NetworkInfo ni : networkInfos) {
        if (ni.getType() == ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI && ni.isConnected())
            return true;
    }
    return false;
}// isWifiAvailable()
```

There are more types in [`ConnectivityManager`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/ConnectivityManager.html) (they start with `TYPE_*`).